# Search for Outlook ID

Tags: exchange, outlook

Is there a way to search for an email with a specific Oulook ID?
I've got a response from a mail archive tool saying that a messag with the Outlook ID

> 00000000A657C7CA2D38D2118CF600A024540C9A07004B44C7CA2D38D2118CF600A024540C9A00000000DD3300006547E177D45A2C47A5E29F0F733EC3C500E428B36D020000

could not be archived. The Outlook ID seems to be a pretty common identifier for third party extension to identify messages, however I couldn't find a way to search for it inside outlook. And it seems *not* to be, identical to the *message ID* on the Exchange server.

Any hints how I may locate the email corresponding to that Oulook ID?

Comment: What you are asking for isn't the message ID but rather the EntryID or the StoreID.  This question would probably be better suited on SO though, as what you are talking about searching for requires scripting/api/MSDN knowledge.

Comment: http://www.taskconnect.com/blog/searching-emails-outlook-add shows how to search on arbitrary fields programmatically. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You must identify if the email not being archived is older than the date the archive was created. The issue cannot be resolved on exchange server's end, but rather there can be a problem on the email client. But this link may help you isolate the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295657.

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the question?

Comment: To sum up @marste's concern, as I understand, the Outlook obtains an error when archiving. That's why outlook is trying to look for an outlook ID of a message. The message being archived is probably older than the archive date. The issue would then be on the client side, not on the exchange side.

Comment: I understand that this is about PST files, but we use this tool:
[link]http://www.opentext.com/What-We-Do/Products/Enterprise-Content-Management/Email-Solutions/OpenText-Email-Archiving-for-Microsoft-Exchange